# Program that calculates binary gap using recursion in python generates recursion error

Tags: python, recursion

I am new at programming (please be nice :)) and I am trying to write a function that calculates the binary gap of a number using recursion by using the modulus function to gather the bits of an integer and then counting the number of 0s between 1s and displaying the longest chain 0s in between two 1s.

For example

```
Input = 10, Binary value = 1010, Binary Gap = 1
Input = 15, Binary value = 1111, Binary Gap = 0
Input = 41, Binary value = 101001, Binary Gap = 2
```

As it stands the code below will always return a 0 if an even number is inputted and always throw a recursion error should an odd number be used. This leads me to believe there is a problem involving the division and it being stuck in an infinite loop but cannot figure out why.

```
def binary_gap(n, foundFirstOne= False, numofZeros= 0):
if n == 0:
    return 0
bit = n % 2
if bit == 1:
    ans = binary_gap((n / 2), True, 0)
else:
    if foundFirstOne == True:
        ans = binary_gap((n / 2), True, numofZeros+1)
    else:
        ans = binary_gap((n / 2), False, 0)
return ans and numofZeros
print(binary_gap(int(input("Please enter a number"))))
```

Comment: Please fix/correct the code indentation first.  Correct format it will NOT work. ;-)

Comment: How does `binary_gap` return something that isn't 0?

Comment: Look at the result of n / 2 and compare it to n // 2 (to fix your infinite recursion problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, write a recursive function to convert decimal to binary (not necessary because there is already a `bin` function). Then, count the gap - there is no point using recursion in this because it is just way too complicated:

```py
def convert_to_binary(n):
    if n > 1:
        return convert_to_binary(n // 2) + str(n % 2)
    return str(n % 2)

def binary_gap(n):
    b = convert_to_binary(n)
    x = b.split('1')[:-1]
    return max(len(d) for d in x)

print(binary_gap(10)) # 1
print(binary_gap(15)) # 0
print(binary_gap(41)) # 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the code indentation problems, it's too *convoluted* to use recursion to get this problem.  Rather you can use simple *strip()* and logic like this:

```
>>> def gap(n):
    ''' find the num's binary gap'''
    sn = bin(n)[2:].strip('0').split('1')
    print(sn)   # just to confirm. can comment out
    return max(len(s) for s in sn)

>>> gap(105); gap(120); gap(121); gap(15)
['', '', '0', '00', '']
2
['', '', '', '', '']
0
['', '', '', '', '00', '']
2
['', '', '', '', '']
0
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you return a value from the function in 2 cases:

1. `n == 0`
2. the function has reached its last line (`return ans and numOfZeroes`)

In the second case, you call `binary_gap` again before returning anything. This means that `binary_gap` will be repeatedly called until `n == 0` in one of the function calls, which is when it will stop recursing. However, in no scenario will your function be called with `n == 0` unless if 0 is the initial input for `n`! This is why your function infinitely recurses.

Rather than changing the recursive approach, this can be solved without recursion using much easier techniques. The builtin `bin` function converts to binary:

```py
n = bin(n)
n = str(n)
n = n[2:]
```

We convert to a string so we can deal with individual digits and we slice from the 2nd digit onward because all python binary digits start with "0b" before the actual binary digit.

Then simply count the longest repeated 0s:

```
n = n.split("1")
print(max([len(zeroSet) for zeroSet in n]))
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the actual question that was asked, why is this experiencing infinite recursion?

Here is your code with a little extra:

```
def binary_gap(n, foundFirstOne= False, numofZeros= 0, depth=0):
    print(f"recursion depth {depth}, n is {n}")
    if n < 0.001:
        print ("I think we've made our point. Use integer division.")
        return 0
    
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    bit = n % 2
    if bit == 1:
        ans = binary_gap((n / 2), True, 0)
    else:
        if foundFirstOne == True:
            ans = binary_gap((n / 2), True, numofZeros+1, depth+1)
        else:
            ans = binary_gap((n / 2), False, 0, depth+1)
    return ans and numofZeros

binary_gap(1)
```

> recursion depth 0, n is 1
> recursion depth 0, n is 0.5
> recursion depth 1, n is 0.25
> recursion depth 2, n is 0.125
> recursion depth 3, n is 0.0625
> recursion depth 4, n is 0.03125
> recursion depth 5, n is 0.015625
> recursion depth 6, n is 0.0078125
> recursion depth 7, n is 0.00390625
> recursion depth 8, n is 0.001953125
> recursion depth 9, n is 0.0009765625
> I think we've made our point. Use integer division.

Compare these in an interpreter:

```
1 / 2  
> 0.5  
1 // 2  
> 0
```

I'd be happy to comment more about how to do this effectively in python, using modulo two arithmetic, if requested.